# WPF MVVM Dependency property binding not working

Tags: wpf, binding, dependency-properties

I'm using a beavior in a TextBox control to filter input via a regex. For this I added a dependency property to get the regex value. When I set directly in xaml the value, It works properly but when I'm trying to pass it with a bind property, the regex value is not setted in the dependency property:

```
public class TextBoxInputRegExBehaviour : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RegularExpressionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("RegularExpression", typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxInputRegExBehaviour), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(".*"));

    public string RegularExpression
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(RegularExpressionProperty); 
        set { SetValue(RegularExpressionProperty, value); }
    }

    ... 
}
```

When using this format, no problem:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Style="{StaticResource ValidableTextBox}">
     <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
         <behaviours:TextBoxInputRegExBehaviour RegularExpression="[0-9.]+$" />
     </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
 </TextBox>
```

But not working with binding:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Style="{StaticResource ValidableTextBox}">
     <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
         <behaviours:TextBoxInputRegExBehaviour RegularExpression="{Binding MyRegExString}" />
     </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
 </TextBox>
```

What did I wrong?

Comment: How are you setting the dependency property? Binding is failing or being over written. If you're over writing the binding, you should use setcurrentvalue rather than the dp bind twoway hack imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Behavior<T>` does not extend `FrameworkElement`, it does not have a `DataContext`. You can either use `Binding.RelativeSource` to traverse the visual tree to find the next parent `FrameworkElement` (and its `DataContext` property).

Or implement an attached bahavior (based on attached properties).
Since attached properties are usually attached to a `FrameworkElement`, you can always bind to the attaching element's `DataContext` (which is what you would naturally do).
You can enforce a type constraint by checking the attaching element's type in the callback and throw an exception if necessary.

**Attached behavior usage example**

```xml
<TextBox TextBoxInputRegExBehaviour.IsEnabled="True" 
         TextBoxInputRegExBehaviour.RegularExpression="{Binding MyRegExString}"
         Text="{Binding MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
         Style="{StaticResource ValidableTextBox}" />
```

**TextBoxInputRegExBehaviour.cs**
Implementation of an attached behavior

```cs
public class TextBoxInputRegExBehaviour : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "IsEnabled", 
        typeof(bool), 
        typeof(TextBoxInputRegExBehaviour), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(bool), OnIsEnabledChanged));
    
    public static void SetIsEnabled(DependencyObject attachingElement, bool value)
        => attachingElement.SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, value);
    public static bool GetIsEnabled(DependencyObject attachingElement)   
        => (bool)attachingElement.GetValue(IsEnabledProperty);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RegularExpressionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "RegularExpression", 
        typeof(string), 
        typeof(TextBoxInputRegExBehaviour), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(".*", OnRegularExpressionChanged));
    
    public static void SetRegularExpression(DependencyObject attachingElement, string value)
        => attachingElement.SetValue(RegularExpressionProperty, value);
    public static string GetRegularExpression(DependencyObject attachingElement)   
        => (string)attachingElement.GetValue(RegularExpressionProperty);

    private static void OnIsEnabledChanged(DependencyObject attachingElement, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
    {
        // Prior to C# 9: if (!(attachingElement is TextBox textBox))
        if (attachingElement is not TextBox textBox)
        {
            // Optionally throw an exception if this makes sense
            return;
        }

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            // TODO::Handle behavior enabled, 
            // for example subscribe to events of the TextBox instance
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO::Handle behavior disabled, 
            // for example unsubscribe from events of the TextBox instance
        }
    }

    private static void OnRegularExpressionChanged(DependencyObject attachingElement, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
    {
        // Prior to C# 9: if (!(attachingElement is TextBox textBox))
        if (attachingElement is not TextBox textBox)
        {
            // Optionally throw an exception if this makes sense
            return;
        }


        // TODO::Handle the changed RegularExpression value
    }


    ... 
}
```

Comment: You are right with DataContext. Unfortunaly, I'm in C# 7.3 version and intellisense says: public static void SetIsEnabled(DependencyObject attachingElement, bool value)
            => element.SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, value); element doesn't exist...

Comment: Sorry, I have used the wrong parameter name. I have fixed it it (it must be `attachingElement.SetValue` and `attachingElement.GetValue` - both 2x).

Comment: Also note that the `IsEnabled` property is optional. It just gives you more control. It is equivalent to an IsAttached property or Attached event.

Comment: So I guess you must also convert the `is not` part in the `if` expression. Pattern matching is only available from C# 9. I have also added a fix for that (see commented code).

Comment: Thanks! I tried your code but unfortunately doesn't run (xaml Exception) with Binding expression, only with hard coded string in xaml...

Comment: Then this is not related to the example code I've provided. It appears your Binding is malformed. Can you show me your current Binding that fails? Can you also show the exception message regarding the Binding?

Comment: The exception: A 'Binding' cannot be set on the property 'SetRegularExpression' of type 'TexBox'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject. xaml: <TextBox Text="{Binding MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Style="{StaticResource ValidableTextBox}" behaviours:TextBoxInputRegExBehaviour.RegularExpression="{Binding RegEx}" behaviours:TextBoxInputRegExBehaviour.IsEnabled="True"/>
the VM:public string RegEx
        {
            get { return "^[1-9][0-9.]*$"; }
        }

Comment: I have just tested the posted code and it works fine. Your error doesn't make much sense. This means I believe you must accidentally doing something wrong. For example is there any code left over that was modified for testing purposes? According to the message you must be defining a Binding somewhere on that targets the `SetRegularExpression` property. When there should be no `SetRegularExpression` property. `SetRegularExpression` is a method. Can you verify that `SetRegularExpression` is a method and there is no binding that targets any `SetRegularExpression` member?

Comment: You are totally right, some testing code was left over. Thanks!

Comment: May I asking you 2 little things: How to suscribe TextBox event in a static method and how to access the property RegularExpression in the class TextBoxInputRegExBehaviour? I'm a bit lost here

Comment: You get the TextBox instance from casting the `attachingElement` parameter to `TextBox` (like I already did in the example). To get attached property values you need the instance that the property was attached to (for example by casting the `attachingElement` parameter or the `sender` parameter of the event handler to `TextBox`). Then use this instance withe the `Get...` and `Set...` methods of the attached property. For example: `string regexPattern = GetRegularExpression(attachingElement)` or `string regexPattern = GetRegularExpression(sender as TextBox)` .

Comment: whaaa I'm tired these days! Thanks for your patience